# why nethogs & iftop numbers for sent traffic are not correlating

Tags: traffic

I am trying to understand the root cause of my high network egress..

GCP network monitoring shows approx 600 KB/s and bills accordingly If I do iftop on my VM, the sent (Tx) traffic sort of correlates with this number.. But if I run nethogs to understand the process which is initiating this traffic, I only get 20%-40% of the number reported by iftop..

Where is the discrepancy in nethogs vs iftop..

Answer (score 0):

Just to continue your previous [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487884/why-nethogs-iftop-numbers-for-sent-traffic-are-not-correlating/69490009#69490009). I updated the answer. Please see below.

Verify on your end if the traffic is TCP or UDP. There's still issue on nethogs when it comes to getting UDP bandwidth.

Refer on links below regarding issues on nethogs.

**GIT HUB** 
[Nethogs significantly underestimating Zoom traffic](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/issues/197) 
[Reported bandwidth seems too low/inaccurate](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/issues/116)

**STACK EXCHANGE** 
[Why doesn't nethogs show correct total](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839777/why-doesnt-nethogs-show-correct-total)

I tried to install the latest version from raboof (8.5-87) on my end using this [guide](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) (Full discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/2537)) to capture both TCP/UDP traffic by running `sudo nethogs -C`. Still the same bandwitdh with 8.2 version. Seems to be that `nethogs` has limitations on displaying bandwidth.